# Undefined method for <variable>_cont in spree - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, spree

I am trying to do a search in the spree backend in reviews listing page. 
But am getting ***undefined method error*** for the fields. Eg: undefined method `title_cont' , undefined method`review _cont'.

Hereby am posting my controller:

***reviews_controller.rb***

```
class Spree::Admin::ReviewsController < Spree::Admin::ResourceController
      helper Spree::ReviewsHelper

     def index
     @reviews = Spree::Review.ransack(params[:q]).result
     end

      def approve
      r = Spree::Review.find(params[:id])

      if r.update_attribute(:approved, true)
      flash[:notice] = Spree.t("info_approve_review")
      else
      flash[:error] = Spree.t("error_approve_review")
      end
      redirect_to admin_reviews_path
      end

      def edit
      if @review.product.nil?
      flash[:error] = Spree.t("error_no_product")
      redirect_to admin_reviews_path and return
      end
      end

      private

      def collection
      params[:q] ||= {}
      @search = Spree::Review.ransack(params[:q])
      @collection = @search.result.includes([:product, :user, :feedback_reviews]).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
      end
      end
```

Model File : ***review.rb***

```
class Spree::Review < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :product, touch: true
      belongs_to :user, :class_name => Spree.user_class.to_s
      has_many   :feedback_reviews

      after_save :recalculate_product_rating, :if => :approved?
      after_destroy :recalculate_product_rating

      validates :name, presence: true
      validates :review, presence: true

      validates :rating, numericality: { only_integer: true,
      greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, 
      less_than_or_equal_to: 5,
      message: Spree.t('you_must_enter_value_for_rating') }


      default_scope { order("spree_reviews.created_at DESC") }

      scope :localized, ->(lc) { where('spree_reviews.locale = ?', lc) }
      scope :most_recent_first, -> { order('spree_reviews.created_at DESC') }
      scope :oldest_first, -> { reorder('spree_reviews.created_at ASC') }
      scope :preview, -> { limit(Spree::Reviews::Config[:preview_size]).oldest_first }
      scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true) }
      scope :not_approved, -> { where(approved: false) }
      scope :default_approval_filter, -> { Spree::Reviews::Config[:include_unapproved_reviews] ? all : approved }

      def feedback_stars
      return 0 if feedback_reviews.size <= 0
      ((feedback_reviews.sum(:rating) / feedback_reviews.size) + 0.5).floor
      end

      def set_search
      @search=Product.search(params[:q])
      end

      def recalculate_product_rating
      self.product.recalculate_rating if product.present?
      end
      end
```

***Index.html.erb***

```
<% content_for :table_filter do %>
<div data-hook="admin_reviews_index_search">
 <%= search_form_for [:admin, @search] do |f| %>   
 <div class="alpha three columns">
    <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag nil, Spree.t(:user) %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont,:size => 25 %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="four columns">
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag nil, Spree.t(:title) -%><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title_cont, :size => 25%>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="four columns">
    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag nil, Spree.t(:review) -%><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :review_cont, :size => 25 ,:value => ""%>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="two columns omega">

</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="form-buttons actions filter-actions" data-hook="admin_reviews_index_search_buttons">
        <%= button Spree.t(:search), 'icon-search' %>
    </div>
<%- end -%>
```

Getting undefined when i use the above mentioned variables. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been solved!

Defined the ransackable_attributes method in associated model `Review.rb` for custom searchable attributes of that model.

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ['title','review','user']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

@cliffs - To be able to search by using ransack gem, you will first have to whitelist all those fields on which you wanna perform the search. So in your `review.rb` model add the following line if you are inheriting it from `Spree::Base` -

`self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes = %w[title, review]`

else if you are inheriting it from `ActiveRecord::Base` you have to define `ransackable_attributes` as a class method

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ['title','review','user']
end
```

and now try to search using `ransack`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tried adding the above in review.rb (model) file. But it results in an error ` no implicit conversion of true into Array `.

Comment: solved the issue by defining the ranksackable method in the model. Thanks for your support.

Comment: my bad, I didn't notice that you are inheriting it from ActiveRecord::Base and not from Spree::Base
Updated my answer